# MySQL select field from string

Tags: mysql, sql, string, select, substring

I have a table with 3 columns:

```
number | number2 | string
________________________________________________________________
     1 |       2 | 0 423 0 2 0 4 2 1 423 521
```

So, how to get a result like this? :

```
1, 2, 423
```

Where 423 is the second number in the string?

Comment: I'm guessing you will have to use your programming language to parse that string and pull out the second number.  What language are you using?

Comment: Do you mean second highest number? (OR) second positional number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) doesn't have a built-in function to split strings, but could MacGyver something up with [`substring_index`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index):

```
SELECT `number`, `number2`, 
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`string`, ' ', 2), ' ', -1)
FROM   my_table
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always use string functions to  remove the first value, and cast the rest to int;

```
SELECT number, 
       number2, 
       CAST(SUBSTR(string, LOCATE(' ', string)) AS SIGNED) number3
FROM mytable;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1a112/4).